# JSF - Example login-ajax - Why it send the form?

Tags: ajax, jsf

Im trying JSF framework. Im a beginner. So i start with a easy [tutorial](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2009/01/21/simple-jsf2ajax-example). This is the code :

```
<h:form id="form1" prependId="false">
    <h:outputScript name="jsf.js" library="javax.faces" target="head" />

    <h:inputText value="#{user.name}" id="name"/>
    <h:inputSecret value="#{user.password}" id="password"/>
    <h:outputText value="#{user.greeting}" id="out"/>

    <br/>

    <h:commandButton value="Login" type="button" onclick="jsf.ajax.request(this, event, {execute: 'name password', render: 'out'}); return false;" />
</h:form>

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean(name = "user")
@RequestScoped
public class UserBean {
   private String name = "";
   private String password;

   public String getName() { return name; }
   public void setName(String newValue) { name = newValue; }

   public String getPassword() { return password; }
   public void setPassword(String newValue) { password = newValue; }

   public String getGreeting() {
       if(name.length()==0) {
           return "Inserisci nickname";
       } else {
           return "Benvenuto "+name;
       }
    }
}
```

In "less words" (when i click on button) :

1 - thanks to `execute: 'name password`, I call the `setName` and `setPassword` (JavaBean methods) with an asynch call;

2 - than, thanks to `render: 'out'` I call `getGreeting`

So, `execute` will be translate as `SET` and `render` as `GET`.

What I would like to know is if I have well understand the process.

Because I have a misunderstanding : if I scan the traffik from client to server, I see that (trought the ajax call) it sends from client to server the form1, name and password (and, as MAGIC, name and password have got the value inserted by me).

So how is this possible?

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't magic. That's normal. Those values are entered in webbrowser. JS/Ajax has access to those values. JS/Ajax will send those values along. How else should server side/JSF know about the newly entered values?

Comment: Yeah of course. I think ajax send it when .setName and .setPassword are called by "execute" right? But why it send also the "form" field? Thats i don't understand...

Comment: That's normal as per HTTP and HTML. All hidden input fields and the pressed button will also be sent as request parameter. This way JSF knows which action has been invoked. There can namely be multiple forms and command buttons/links. I'd suggest to play around with plain HTTP/HTML first before diving into JSF.

Comment: Uhm... I come from PHP/JQuery approch. When i do an ajax call i send only few parameter, not the whole form/input fields. Maybe this is just the way JSF working out :)

Comment: With such a basic setup you're sending to a different URL everytime wherein you can write specific code which is expecting exactly those parameters. In JSF however, everything comes in the `FacesServlet` as a single point of entry (as Controller of MVC). It has to decide based on the parameters what to do. This way you end up with a simple XHTML page as View and a simple Javabean as Model. Doing so with "basic" PHP/jQuery would involve a lot more work. I'm sure that when you refactor it to the same degree as JSF, you would need to send those extra parameters as well.

Comment: OH! I see. Thats also mean that on JSF i can't load dinamically new element? (but update only the ones I already have on client-side page?)

Comment: Yes, but they can in turn be dynamically controlled by `rendered` attribute.

Comment: Uhm...is not so clear how to do it! I open a new topic in few minuts, its another argument hehe! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You need to take into account that the to-be-updated `id` has not to be placed on an element which isn't rendered to the client side. I've answered several of such problems before. For example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231206/how-to-recognize-java-server-faces-2-0-composite-components-when-using-ajax/4232394#4232394).

Comment: Uhm ok, i'll take a look. Just as information (because is not so clear) : RichFaces is for JSF (2.0) as JQuery is for Javascript, right? Just a sort of library...! Because i read that if i use directly RichFaces i can safe a lot of works. Of course i need to practice with JSF 2.0 "basic" before... :)

Comment: RichFaces is just a 3rd party JSF component library which is to be used on top of basic JSF implementation. That kind of libraries usually just saves a lot of UI (look'n'feel) works. I myself don't use it by the way. I'm a PrimeFaces user. jQuery is already shipped in RichFaces (and PrimeFaces).

Comment: I tried your example. The problems is that i need to load the dinamic source in another context of the site, which is not in the same form. So render dont find it. Yes, maybe is better if i open a new topic :)

Comment: I bet that it's completely unrelated to ajax (and that you would have exactly the same problem when not utilizing ajaxical powers) :)

Comment: Yes maybe you are right. Anyway i post a topic...would help me anyway to understand better of how this frameworks works :)